# Spring Actuator - metrics aggregation from docker containers

Tags: spring, docker, monitoring, microservices, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring Boot REST service application. This application uses Spring Actuator to display metrics and health information. How can I aggregate this information from two or more containers running the same application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export the metrics to a central system.

> Spring Boot provides a couple of implementations of a marker interface
>   called `Exporter` which can be used to copy metric readings from the
>   in-memory buffers to a place where they can be analyzed and displayed.

More specifically personally I like exporting metrics to statsD

> To export metrics to Statsd, make sure first that you have added
>   `com.timgroup:java-statsd-client` as a dependency of your project
>   (Spring Boot provides a dependency management for it). Then add a
>   `spring.metrics.export.statsd.host` value to your `application.properties`
>   file. Connections will be opened to port `8125` unless a
>   `spring.metrics.export.statsd.port` override is provided. You can use
>   `spring.metrics.export.statsd.prefix` if you want a custom prefix.

The information above is all from the Spring Boot documentation on metrics: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html